# How to obtain google map images "satellite view without labels" using python

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know about Google map static API which can return map as an image. But it returns static view and I need satellite view of google map without labels for my system. I've been searching for solution for so long but couldn't find any.
any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Static Maps API *can* return satellite imagery.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to get static maps satellite imagery via official service and hide all labels on it (except Google logo and copyrights) you can set map type to satellite and apply styles that hide all labels with Static Maps API. For example,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=39.279117%2C-89.881745&zoom=18&size=600x400&maptype=satellite&style=feature%3Aall%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Otherwise if you want download and store images for your needs, stitch them or remove copyright labels the solution might be not compliant with Google Maps API Terms of Service.

Look at the following sections of Terms of Service.

Paragraph 10.1 (a)

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

That means you cannot scrap satellite imagery for your needs and store it in your storage.

Paragraph 10.5 (g)

> **No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or proprietary rights notices.** You will not:
>
> - remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms, or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices; or
> - falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other labels of the origin or source of material.

Finally, paragraph 10.5 (b)

> **No derivative works.** You will not modify or create a derivative work based on any Content unless expressly permitted to do so under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; or (iii) tracing or copying the copyrightable elements of Google’s maps or building outlines and creating a new work, such as a new mapping or navigation dataset.

I hope my answer addresses your question.